# Swift Error "[T] is not a subtype of"

Tags: swift, generics

Running into a bit of a trouble with a Swift tutorial...

```
func exchange<T>(inout data:[T], i:Int, j:Int)
{
    let temp = data[i];
    data[i] = data[j];
    data[j] = temp;
}

func swapLeft<T: Comparable>(data: [T], index:Int)
{
    for i in reverse(1...index)
    {
        if (data[i] < data[i - 1])
        {
            exchange(&data, i, i - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

var data = [Int]();
data = [84, 0, 1, 63, 20, 12, 11, 63, 13, 99, 89, 98, 94, 31, 88, 48, 90, 30, 68, 43];
swapLeft(data, 6);
data
```

In `swapLeft` the exchange call produces the error:

> Playground execution failed: error: :32:13: error: '[T]' is not a subtype of '@lvalue $T3'

I have a vague assumption that it's because `swapLeft` uses a Comparable generic but exchange uses a non-Comparable one. But changing exchange to `func exchange<T: Comparable>...` wont fix it. Does anyone know what to do there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is still about `inout`. Your `swapLeft` function is missing the `inout` specifier:

```
func swapLeft<T: Comparable>(inout data: [T], index:Int)
```

and when you call it, you have to dereferentiate the array:

```
swapLeft(&data, 6);
```

Comment: Thank you! Easier fixed than I thought.

Comment: I see you've removed the "answered" flag... is that by mistake or is my solution not working?

Comment: SO wouldn't let me check it for several minutes after reading, sorry!